# Spotfire How column reranks when data is limited by expression or filtered?

Tags: spotfire

I have a shapefile in Spotfire and in the tableview of it I have a column displaying DenseRank. For example, if limit data by expression from the full 100 rows in the table to just 30, the DenseRank does not change. How can I perform this task?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Your question is unclear now, please improve it. How do you calculate your rank - in a calculated column in the table / in the table? What type of table do you have? What is the exact expression you use? Some sample data / Screenshot might also help. ...

Comment: When I rank by calculated column the rank does not change when I filter or limit data by expression. I need it to update when a filter is applied.

Comment: you just say the same. Please improve your question to let us understand it; don't expect others to help you without investing in it to explain it clearly.

Comment: I think this is pretty straight forward but if it helps, here is an example. I can create a calculated column using the DenseRank function. The problem is when I filter data, the DenseRank output does not update dynamically. I believe I need to use a TERR script to do this. My question is, how can I do this?

Comment: TERR script won't manage that either,  or it'll be very inefficient.  Make a cross table and calculate rank there with custom expression, that will respect filters.

Comment: Chris, ranks and other functions applied in a calculated column won't change unless the entire data-source changes (rows added / removed), you need to do this in your visualization aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to dynamically rank data based on filtering or marking. If you create a data function as simple as "tableout <- tablein" then you can pass the original filtered and/or marked table to a new table. From there, insert calculated column on the new table and it will recalculate each time.

Answer (score 0):

Tableview does not allow dynamic calculations, unless you have a Document Property in the expression, The calculated column expression executes whenever Document Property value chane (or Calculations refreshed), for your scenario I think instead of using filter create a property control with Fixed values (10,20,30...100) or Values from a column (the one you are using to filter data). and use Document Property linked to the Property Control in your Calculated Column Expression .....